# Klein bottle is homeomorphic to unit square quotient

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, klein-bottle

let $I=[0,1]^2$.

Let's provide $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with the group operation:
$(k, l) ∗ (k' , l' ) = (k + (−1)^l k' , l + l' )$

Let's then define $\mathbb{Z}^2$ action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by:

$((k, l)* (x, y)) → ((−1)^l x + k, y + l)$

This action is free and proper so the quotient $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$  is a differential manifold, that we define as the Klein bottle.

Show that K is hemeomorphic to $I^2/∼$ where $∼$ is the equivalence relashinship $(0, y) ∼ (1, y)$ and $(x, 0) ∼ (1 − x, 1)$.

What I did:

Let's take the injection $i: I^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $.

Let $p: I^2 \rightarrow I^2/ ∼$ and $\pi: \mathbb{R}^2  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2  $ be the canonical projections.

By the universal property of the quotient, there exists a unique $\overline{i}: I^2/ ∼ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$

I need to prove that $\overline{i}$ is a homeomorphism.
It is obvious that it is $\overline{i}$ is continuous (because $i$ is continuous) and proper(as $I^2/ ∼$ is compact).

I don't see how to prove it is a bijection.
In this try, I didn't use the equivalence relationship definition, nor the group action definition. So I wonder if there is an explicit formulation of such a homermorphism. 
Thank you for any help in the right direction .

Comment: For points $p$ of the interior of the square, note that it is sufficient to show that $(\mathbb{Z}^{2}.p) \cap I = \{p\}$